# Continuity of a bilinear form on $H^1(0,2)$

Tags: integration, inequality, continuity, sobolev-spaces, bilinear-form

**Problem Statement:** Let $H := H^1(0,2) := W^{1,2}(0,2)$ and define the function $B : H^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ by

$$B(f,g) := \int_0^2\!\! f'g' + \int_0^1\!\! f \int_0^1\!\! g$$

Then $B$ is a bilinear form; I wish to show it is continuous, in the sense that $\exists C \ge 0$ such that, for any $f,g \in H$, we have

$$|B(f,g)| \le C \cdot \|f\|_H\cdot  \|g\|_H$$

**Update:** It has occurred to me that this arises as part of Exercise $8.25$ in Haim Brezis' *Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces, and Partial Differential Equations.*

---

$
\newcommand{\ip}[2]{\left\langle #1 , #2 \right\rangle}
\newcommand{\n}[1]{\|#1\|}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\|#1\|}
\newcommand{\nc}{\newcommand}
\nc{\ipw}[2]{\ip{#1}{#2}_{W^{1,2}(0,2)}}
\nc{\nw}[1]{\norm{#1}_{W^{1,2}(0,2)}}
\nc{\ipl}[2]{\ip{#1}{#2}_{L^2(0,2)}}
\nc{\nl}[1]{\norm{#1}_{L^2(0,2)}}
\nc{\al}[1]{\begin{align*}#1\end{align*}}
\nc{\abs}[1]{\left|#1\right|}
\nc{\para}[1]{\left(#1\right)}
$
**My Attempts:** As I understand it, the relevant norms and inner products come in from $L^2$ as so:

$$\al{
\ip{f}{g}_{L^2(0,2)} &:= \int_0^2 \!\! fg \\
\norm{f}_{L^2(0,2)} &:= \sqrt{ \int_0^2 \!\!f^2 } \\
\ipw{f}{g} &:= \ip{f}{g}_{L^2(0,2)} + \ip{f'}{g'}_{L^2(0,2)} \\
&= \int_0^2\!\!fg + \int_0^2 \!\!f'g' \\
\nw{f} &:= \sqrt{ \ipw{f}{f} } \\
&= \sqrt{\ip{f}{f}_{L^2(0,2)} + \ip{f'}{f'}_{L^2(0,2)} } \\
&= \sqrt{ \int_0^2 \!\!f^2 + \int_0^2\!\! (f')^2 }
}$$

Hence we want to show $\exists C \ge 0$ such that for all $f,g \in W^{1,2}(0,2)$,

$$\abs{B(f,g)} \le C \sqrt{ \para{ \int_0^2\!\! f^2 + \int_0^2 \!\!(f')^2 }\para{ \int_0^2 \!\!g^2 + \int_0^2\!\! (g')^2 } }$$

I've tried working this in a few ways, but the product of the integrals proves to be the peskiest bit. For instance, running through some basic ideas (triangle inequality, Cauchy-Schwarz) in a "forward" sense, I found

$$
\al{
\abs{B(f,g)}
&= \abs{ \int_0^2 \!\!f'g' + \para{ \int_0^1\!\! f } \para{ \int_0^1\!\! g } }   \\
&\le \abs{ \int_0^2 \!\!f'g' }+ \abs{ \int_0^1\!\! f } \abs{ \int_0^1\!\! g }   \\
&\le  \int_0^2\!\!\abs{ f'g' }+  \para{ \int_0^1\!\! \abs{f }}\para{ \int_0^1 \!\!\abs{ g }}    \\
&\le  \int_0^2\!\!\abs{ f'g' }+  \para{ \int_0^2\!\! \abs{f }}\para{ \int_0^2 \!\!\abs{ g }}  \tag{$\ast$} \\
&= \ipl{ \abs{f'} }{\abs{g'}} + \ipl{ \abs{f} }{1} \cdot \ipl{\abs{g}}{1}  \\
&\le \nl{ \abs{f'} }\cdot \nl{\abs{g'}} + \nl{ \abs{f} } \cdot \nl{1} \cdot \nl{\abs{g}} \cdot \nl{1}   \\
&= \nl{ \abs{f'} }\cdot \nl{\abs{g'}} + 2 \cdot \nl{ \abs{f} }  \cdot \nl{\abs{g}}    \\
&= \sqrt{ \para{ \int_0^2 \!\!(f')^2 } \para{ \int_0^2\!\! (g')^2 } } + 2 \sqrt{ \para{ \int_0^2\!\! f^2 } \para{ \int_0^2\!\! g^2 } }
}$$

...and from here, nothing really comes to mind.

Reaching the fourth line, or something like it, seems to be essential so I can "extend" those integrals to being over $(0,2)$ in lieu of $(0,1)$, making them mesh more amicably with the Sobolev norms. The "loosest" formulation of the work up to that point would have in particular

$$\abs{B(f,g)} \le\abs{ \int_0^2\!\! f'g' }+  \para{ \int_0^2 \!\!\abs{f }}\para{ \int_0^2 \!\!\abs{ g }}$$

by applying triangle inequality later, but it doesn't seem to "get" me anything. I certainly can't extend the bounds without having the absolute value of the inputs either, as otherwise I could actually lose, not gain, value.

So instead I tried working backwards (i.e. assuming $C$ exists and working from the right- to the left-hand sides, in the hope somehow I might reach an intermediate step:

$$\al{
&C \cdot \nw{f} \cdot \nw{g} \\
&= C \sqrt{ \para{ \int_0^2\!\! f^2 + \int_0^2\!\! (f')^2 }\para{ \int_0^2 \!\!g^2 + \int_0^2 \!\!(g')^2 } } \\
&= C \sqrt{ \int_0^2\!\! f^2 \int_0^2 \!\!g^2 + \int_0^2 \!\!f^2 \int_0^2 \!\!(g')^2 + \int_0^2\!\! (f')^2 \int_0^2\!\! g^2 + \int_0^2\!\! (f')^2 \int_0^2 \!\!(g')^2 } \\
&\ge C  \para{ \sqrt{ \int_0^2\!\! f^2 \int_0^2\!\!g^2 } + \sqrt{\int_0^2\!\! f^2 \int_0^2 \!\!(g')^2 }+ \sqrt{\int_0^2 \!\!(f')^2 \int_0^2\!\! g^2} +\sqrt{ \int_0^2 \!\!(f')^2 \int_0^2\!\! (g')^2 } }\\
&= C \para{ \nl{f} \nl{g} + \nl{f} \nl{g'} + \nl{f'} \nl{g} + \nl{f'} \nl{g'} } \\
&\ge C \para{ \abs{ \ipl{f}{g} } +  \abs{ \ipl{f}{g'} } + \abs{ \ipl{f'}{g} } + \abs{ \ipl{f'}{g'} }    } \\
&\ge C \para{ \abs{ \ipl{f}{g} }   + \abs{ \ipl{f'}{g'} }    } \\
&\ge C \abs{ \ipl{f}{g}  +  \ipl{f'}{g'}   }   \\
&= C \abs{ \ipw f g } \\
&= C \abs{ \int_0^2 \!\!fg + \int_0^2\!\! f'g' } 
}$$

Sadly, none of this seemed to pan out either, and didn't get me any real insights, though I feel like it's close somehow.

---

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I might proceed in either sense, or perhaps an approach or angle I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close to the end: we have $\|f\|_{L^2},\|f'\|_{L^2} \leq \|f\|_{W^{1,2}}$ (same for $g$), therefore
$$\|f'\|_{L^2}\|g'\|_{L^2} + 2\|f\|_{L^2}\|g\|_{L^2} \leq 3 \|f\|_{W^{1,2}}\|g\|_{W^{1,2}}.$$
The expression on the left-hand side appeared in your first attempt. By the way, you can get a better constant if you use Cauchy--Schwarz on the integral over $(0,1)$ and then extend the interval.